# Snakemake input rule defintion via lambda + Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, parameters, snakemake, directed-acyclic-graphs

Sorry if this is gonna be probably a duplication of other questions, but I couldn't figure to debug what's going on in my case.
Got a dataframe like this:

```
       Sample  gender phenotype subject_id
0  ERR35175    male     tumor         13
1  ERR35176    male   control         13
2  ERR35177  female     tumor         14
3  ERR35178  female   control         14
4  ERR35179    male     tumor         16
5  ERR35180    male   control         16
```

Given a `subject_id`, I need to give in input either the `tumor` and the `control` sample from the dataframe, concatenating with path from config and file termination, to produce an output which uses the `subject_id`. To do so, I've written this rule (under file `snv_calling.smk`):

```
rule Mutect2:
    input:
        tumor=lambda wc: config["datadirs"]["BQSR_2"]+'/%s_recal.pass2.bam' %df[(df.phenotype == "tumor") & (df.subject_id == [wc.patient])].Sample.values[0],
        normal=lambda wc: config["datadirs"]["BQSR_2"]+'/%s_recal.pass2.bam' %df[(df.phenotype == "control") & (df.subject_id == [wc.patient])].Sample.values[0]
    output:
        vcf=config["datadirs"]["VCF"]+"/{patient}.vcf"
    shell:
    """
    gatk Mutect2 \
    -I {input.tumor} \
    -I {input.normal} \
    -O {output.vcf}
    """
```

Inside the `Snakefile`:

```
PATIENT=['13','14','16']
rule all:
    input:
        expand(config["datadirs"]["VCF"]+"/"+"{patient}.vcf", patient=PATIENT)
```

It gives me this error, where line 37 is the first input argument:

```
InputFunctionException in line 37 of ../rules/snv_calling.smk:
Error:
  ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (0,), (1,))
Wildcards:
  patient=13
Traceback:
  File "../rules/snv_calling.smk", line 45, in <lambda>
```

I'm struggle to understand what's going on, because it seems that the wildcards `patient` is assigned properly from the error. If I run the function outside of Snakemake there's no error against the `PATIENT` list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters are stored in a dataframe, and there is a handy utility for working with tabulated parameters, [`Paramspace`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html?highlight=Paramspace#parameter-space-exploration). Below is a rough take on your specific case, but it will need some adjustments for command syntax and paths.

First step is to reshape the data for easier workflow:

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

data = StringIO(
    """index Sample  gender phenotype subject_id
0  ERR35175    male     tumor         13
1  ERR35176    male   control         13
2  ERR35177  female     tumor         14
3  ERR35178  female   control         14
4  ERR35179    male     tumor         16
5  ERR35180    male   control         16"""
)

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep="\s+")

df = df.pivot(
    index=["subject_id", "gender"], values="Sample", columns="phenotype"
).reset_index()

#phenotype  subject_id  gender   control     tumor
#0                  13    male  ERR35176  ERR35175
#1                  14  female  ERR35178  ERR35177
#2                  16    male  ERR35180  ERR35179
```

Now, create the parameter space:

```py
from snakemake.utils import Paramspace
paramspace = Paramspace(df, filename_params='*')
```

Finally, modify the rules to use the parameter space:

```py
rule all:
    input:
        paramspace.instance_patterns

rule Mutect2:
    output:
        done=touch(paramspace.wildcard_pattern),
    params:
        parameters=paramspace.instance,
    shell:
        """
        echo {params.parameters[gender]}
        echo {params.parameters[tumor]}
        echo {params.parameters[control]}
        """
```

Update:

It's possible to adapt it to work with intermediate outputs. The parameter space acts as a pandas dataframe, so it's possible to select columns of interest:

```py
rule all:
    input:
        paramspace.instance_patterns,


rule some_rule:
    output:
        test=paramspace[["gender"]].wildcard_pattern,


rule Mutect2:
    input:
        test=paramspace[["gender"]].wildcard_pattern,
    output:
        done=touch(paramspace.wildcard_pattern),
    params:
        parameters=paramspace.instance,
    shell:
        """
        echo {params.parameters[gender]}
        echo {params.parameters[tumor]}
        echo {params.parameters[control]}
        """
```

Comment: Many thanks, I was not aware of this function. Passing it as a parameter does not give me a control on input files, as they're created from a previous rule. Any workaround?

Comment: There is no need for a workaround, only need to explicitly specify which columns are needed in a specific file.

Comment: Thanks, although I've found the way to do it with lambda as in the question, this is way more elegant.